# C# How to get count of objects where some field is "undefined"?

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I just trying to get all objects where field "fbLogged" is false or undefined, but query ignores objects with "undefined" value, how to fix it?
I have already tried conditions like

```
WhereEqualTo("fbLogged",null);
```

or

```
WhereEqualTo("fbLogged","");
```

and it does not works.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try [`.WhereDoesNotExist("fbLogged")`](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/M_Parse_ParseQuery_1_WhereDoesNotExist.htm).

Comment: .WhereDoesNotExist does not work too